# Net force acting on conductor in a circular magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose you have a completely straight electrical conductor with a current, travelling from the vertically downwards direction to the upwards direction. The magnetic field would thus be circular, correct? So, since the magnetic field direction will be going in a circular path, will the magnetic forces around the conductor all act inwards/outwards such that they net out and there is no net force on the conductor?
Sorry in advance if what im saying makes no sense or is confusing, i suck at explaining things/articulating my thoughts sometimes lol.

Answer (score 1):

The self forces on a current-carrying conductor act *inwards* to squeeze the wire  into a smaller cross section. This is called the [pinch effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)).